# how to make tar exclude hidden directories

Tags: hidden, tar

When I want to exclude directories when taring, I typically use syntax like this:

```
tar -zcf /backup/backup.tar.gz --exclude="/home/someuser/.ssh" /home/someuser
```

How can I modify this to exclude all hidden directories, for example, in addition to .ssh/, I also want to exclude .vnc/, .wine/, etc.

Answer (score 73):

You can use `--exclude=".*"`

```
$ tar -czvf test.tgz test/
test/
test/seen
test/.hidden
$ tar --exclude=".*" -czvf test.tgz test/
test/
test/seen
```

Be careful if you are taring the current directory, since it will also be excluded by this pattern matching.

```
$ cd test
$ tar --exclude=".*" -czvf test.tgz ./
$ tar -czvf test.tgz ./
./
./seen
./.hidden
```

Then you need to use `--exclude='.[^/]*'` as described [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38108/why-does-tar-exclude-create-an-empty-archive)

```
$ tar --exclude='.[^/]*' -czvf test.tgz ./
./
./seen
```

Comment: Or just using --exclude=".+", and setting the path to be "."

Comment: It seems `--exculde=".*"` is now positional and needs to go first and otherwise has no effect: `tar --exclude=".*" -czvf test.tgz directory_to_be_archived`